# Unable to determine the value for the property dfc.data.dir (Documentum)

Tags: eclipse, documentum

I am trying to get eclipse setup on my new Windows 7 64 bit machine for Documentum DFC development. I replicated everything I could think of from my old machine but I am still getting this error when trying to connect to my doc base:

Unable to determine the value for the property dfc.data.dir

[image]

I have my project pointed at the correct directory:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Anyone know what the issue be?

Comment: Which version of Documentum are you working with ? The behavior of dfc.properties depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you point the eclipse dfc.properties to your c:\Documentum\config\dfc.properties?

I don´t know how you configured your eclipse installation but the path, relative to composer, should be:

..\Composer\plugins\com.emc.ide.external.dfc_1.0.0\documentum.config

Answer (score 0):

Try putting dfc.properties at the root of a source folder of your project.